# How can one user download a file from another users computer through a website?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ruby

I want to make a web app in which one user leaves their computer on with the website on, and another user can download a file off their computer. The user would have to specify which file they'd allow to be downloaded off their computer, but, it has to be completely between those two computers. The user that leaves his computer on would be like a server for other users trying to download it. I don't want my own servers handling all the traffic. Also, it all has to be through a website, not a program.

The person that leaves the computer on would see a page with a status bar with how many people are downloading his file, and he can press a cancel button at anytime, in order to stop people to have access to his file.

I saw something called a 'flash java socket' thing... Could that attempt to complete my task?

http://www.google.com/search?q=flash+java+socket&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari

Comment: Are you talking about file sharing via messenger kind of thing..

Comment: I don't know if leaving your server out of the file transfer is even remotely possible. The whole point of the web is communication between a client and a server. If you're taking *your* server out of that equation, wouldn't someone else's computer have to step in? And wouldn't that require installing actual programs on that someone else's computer?

Comment: FTP with restrictions and user accounts.

Comment: damn it..i found a site that did almost exactly this awhile back, but i cant remember what it was called. i think it used flash or something? i dunno. but basically i think you chose a file on your computer, then sent your friend a link and then it established a connection and it would send the file directly to them. that'd be the hard part...then you could record a few stats if you wanted.

Comment: That sounds like one of the intended use cases of Opera Unite. Not all by itself however, needs specific client preparations still. And of course, that excludes other browsers. But with a generic user script / widget you might come closer.

Comment: FTP connections? or some sort of P2P plugins, VPN , Tunneling.. This question is debatable and too broad. Be more specific... i vote close

Comment: this isn't the site i found originally, but it seems to do pretty much the same thing. http://www.filesovermiles.com/ i don't know how it works, but i'd investigate flash solutions, because you're not going to be able to do this with just javascript. you'll need flash or silverlight or something like that.

Comment: Sounds more like [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29) or [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) than a web page to me.

Comment: Sounds like an attempt to reinvent several different wheels, without enough knowledge of the networking and security issues. It's also [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for SO.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of hurdles to this:

1. Web pages can't accept incoming connections
2. Browsers don't allow you access to the filesystem (well, traditionally)
3. Most people are using NAT behind a router, so you need a port mapped to access the computer.
4. IP addresses change, some more than others.

There are also a number of workarounds that might be helpful:

1. Flash and Java can access the filesystem.
2. To limited degree flash/java running on a webpage can send files over the internet (cross-site limitations)
3. Java applets *may* be able to monitor the external IP address of the computer they are on and push notifications back to the server.
4. Services like DynDNS can provide static addresses for dynamic IPs.

Web screen-sharing apps like WebEx use Java to share screens, so you might really be able to do what you need using a Java Applet. With straight HTML/JavaScript you're outta luck though.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to effectively turn the client's computer into a web server to make this possible.  It would have to have a publicly accessible IP address which your server would log and give to the second client's machine to query directly.

Comment: Hmm, i understand guys, but let's look at limewire, how computers were somewhat like servers... Can their be some possible FTP magic, or ruby/java beauty?

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be possible through just the browser there would need to be a program running on the users computers to handle the file transfer if you wanted to not handle any traffic on your own servers.

Comment: And I guess what I meant by "not handle any traffic on my own servers" was that I wouldn't have to buy servers where users would upload to, and from there people can download the file...

Comment: The only way to keep this in the browser would be to store the data yourself on your servers, hence me saying not possible without writing a program that users would have to install. like every other peer-to-peer application

Answer (score 1):

Technically this is possible. Although you will be using your website more as a place to 'connect users' rather then show files. You need the following things:

Users must:

- have a static-ip, or DNS.
- be able to securely give those id's to people in order to download files from one another without being open to intrusion.
- provide you with a list of files they have available for download, (or let you crawl their directories).

In the end, you end up with only one thing: "bitTorrent".

This already exists.

Comment: Wait I don't understand... Bittorent. What does that have to do with it?

Comment: So bitTorrent... I see what you're saying. Users provide an ip adress, other users can download file from that ip... But I'm confused on the bittorent that already exists part

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as the transfer wouldn't happen in the browser as the question was asking. The transfer would be managed by a program that he would have to write or use a 3rd party one.

Comment: Actually it does answer the question. What hes asking is impossible, I have provided the closest possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to install a web server (and optionally ftp server on the computers which have the files), and make their ips publicly accesible.

Only for Internet Explorer, you could install (develop?) an ActiveX to read your computer files, but your computer would need high permissions.

If you are not allowed to install anything, the short answer is **no, you can not**

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't include it in your tags, but if the computer in question has Python installed, you can serve up the current directory tree with:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

This will make the directory available at `http://$HOSTNAME:8000/`.